# Convergence of sum of triangular array of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, martingales

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0},\mathbb{P}\right)$ be a filtered probability space. For given $t>0$ consider the equi-spaced partition $t_{j,n}=j\,\Delta_n$ with $\Delta_n=t/n$ of $[0,t]$. In this framework, consider a triangular array of random variable $\{\xi_{j,n}\}_{j=1,\dots,n}$ such that $\xi_{j,n}\in\mathcal{F}_{j\,\Delta_n}$ for all $j$. In what follows, I denote with $\stackrel{u.c.p}{\longrightarrow}$ the uniform, on $[0,t]$, convergence in probability and with $\mathbb{E}_{j}[\cdot]$ the $\mathcal{F}_{j\,\Delta_n}$-conditional expectation.
This is the lemma I want to prove

**Lemma.**
If the following conditions are satisfied:
$$
\sum^{\lfloor t/\Delta_n \rfloor}_{j=1}\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}] \stackrel{u.c.p}{\longrightarrow}0,\quad (1)
$$
$$
\sum^{\lfloor t/\Delta_n \rfloor}_{j=1}\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi^2_{j,n}] \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0\quad(2)
$$
then
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor t/\Delta_n\rfloor}\xi_{j,n}\stackrel{u.c.p}{\longrightarrow}0
$$

**Attempt of Proof.**
For given $t\geq 0$ call $n=\lfloor t/\Delta_n \rfloor$ where $\Delta_n\longrightarrow0$ as $n\longrightarrow\infty$. We have
$$
\left|\sum_{j=1}^n\xi_{j,n}\right|\leq \sum_{j=1}^n\left|\xi_{j,n}\right| \leq \underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n|\xi_{j,n}-\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}]|}_{\mathsf{A}_n}+\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n|\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}]|}_{\mathsf{B}_n}.
$$
For $n$ given, the discrete-time process $M_{k,n}=\sum_{j=1}^k(\xi_{j,n}-\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}])$, with $k=1,\dots,n$, is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{G}_{k,n}=\mathcal{F}_{k\,\Delta_n}$. In fact we have
$$
\mathbb{E}_k[M_{k+1,n}]=\mathbb{E}_{k}[M_{k,n}+\xi_{k+1,n}-\mathbb{E}_{k}[\xi_{k+1,n}]] = M_{k,n},
$$
where the $\mathcal{G}_{k,n}$-measurability of $M_{k,n}$ derives from the
the $\mathcal{F}_{k\,\Delta_n}$-measurability of $\xi_{k,n}$. The idea is that condition (1) should imply $\mathsf{B}_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0$ and the Doob's martingale inequality applied to $M_{k,n}$ plus condition (2) should imply $\mathsf{A}_n\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0$. The problems that I face are thus:

I) Condition (1) is equivalent to
$$
\sup_{s\in[0,t]}\left|\sum^{\lfloor s/\Delta_n \rfloor}_{j=1}\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}]\right|\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}0
$$
which is weaker (right?) than $\sum_{j=1}^n|\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}]|\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow}0$.

II) The  Doob's martingale inequality (with $p=2$) prescribes that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\max_{q\leq k}M_{q,n}\right)^2\right]\leq C\,\mathbb{E}\left[M^2_{k,n}\right]
$$
A simple computation shows that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[M^2_{k,n}\right] = \sum_{j=1}^k\mathbb{E}\left[\xi_{j,n}^2-\mathbb{E}_{j-1}\left[\xi_{j,n}\right]^2\right]
$$
and, as for point I), I don't know how to use condition (1) or (2) to finish the proof.

Am I missing something obvious? Or, perhaps, am I moving on a dead end track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give a proof of what you want. Using your notations, let
\begin{align*}
 M_{k,n}&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(\xi_{j,n}- \mathsf{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}]),
 \quad k\le l =\Big[\frac{t}{\Delta_n}\Big],  \\
   \langle M\rangle_{k,n}&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\mathsf{E}_{j-1}[ (\xi_{j,n}- \mathsf{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}])^2 ], \qquad k\le l.
\end{align*}
Then it is easy to verify that $\{M_{k,n}^2-\langle M\rangle_{k,n},\; 1\le k \le l\} $
is a martingale for each $n\ge 1$ and following inequality is true for $\epsilon>0, \delta>0$,
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(\sup_{k\le l}|M_{k,n}|\ge \delta)\le \frac{\epsilon}{\delta^2} 
 +\mathsf{P}(\langle M\rangle_{l,n}\ge \epsilon). \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
(The proof of (3) and its more general cases, please refer to
J. Jacod, and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003.
p.35, Lemma 1.3.30. ).

Meanwhile,
\begin{gather*}
 (2): \sum_{j=1}^{l}\mathsf{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}^2]\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}0\\
 \text{$\;$}\hspace{3cm}\Downarrow  (\text{by } \mathsf{E}_{j-1}[(\xi_{j,n} - \mathsf{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}])^2] 
    \le  \mathsf{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}^2])  \\
 \langle M\rangle_{l,n} 
    =\sum_{j=1}^{l}\mathsf{E}_{j-1}[(\xi_{j,n} - \mathsf{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}])^2] \overset{p}{\longrightarrow}0\\
 \Downarrow (\text{by } (3))\\
 \sup_{k\le l}\Big|\sum_{j=1}^{k}(\xi_{j,n}- 
    \mathsf{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}])\Big| =
 \sup_{k\le l}|M_{k,n}| \overset{p}{\longrightarrow}0\\
 \Downarrow (\text{by } (1))\\
 \sup_{k\le l}\Big|\sum_{j=1}^{k}\xi_{j,n}\Big|\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}0.
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 1):

In your first line, plus-and-subtract before using triangle inequality,
$$\biggl|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\xi_{j,n}\biggr|=\biggl|\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\xi_{j,n}-\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}])+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}]\biggr|\leq\biggl|\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\xi_{j,n}-\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}])\biggr|+\biggl|\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\xi_{j,n}]\biggr|.$$
It gives a stronger upper bound: above line only uses the triangle inequality once (counting of the basic form $|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|$), while your attempt uses $2(n-1)$ times.