# Convergence of sum of triangular array of random variables-II

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

This question is related [to a previous of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314049/convergence-of-sum-of-triangular-array-of-random-variables).

Suppose that $\{\xi_{j,n}|n\in\mathbb{N},j=1,...,n\}$ is a triangular array of random variables. Given a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ we know that $\xi_{j,n}\in\mathcal{F}_{t_{j,n}}$, where $0=t_{0,n}<t_{1,n}<\cdots<t_{n,n}=t$ is a partition of $[0,t]$ and let $\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\cdot]$ indicate the conditional expected value with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{t_{j-1,n}}$. I need to prove that if
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{j-1}\left[\left|\xi_{j,n}\right|\right]\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} 0
$$
then
$$
\max_{k\leq n}\left|\sum_{j=1}^k\xi_{j,n}\right|\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} 0.\quad(1)
$$
My problem is the following. Using Markov's inequality I get
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\max_{k\leq n}\left|\sum_{j=1}^k\xi_{j,n}\right|\geq\varepsilon\right]\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{k\leq n}\left|\sum_{j=1}^k\xi_{j,n}\right|\right]}{\varepsilon}\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{k\leq n}\sum_{j=1}^k\left|\xi_{j,n}\right|\right]}{\varepsilon} = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\left|\xi_{j,n}\right|\right]}{\varepsilon} = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{j-1}{\left|\xi_{j,n}\right|}\right]}{\varepsilon}.\quad(2) 
$$
Since, by hypothesis, $X_n\doteq \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{j-1}[\left|\xi_{j,n}\right|]\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow}0$ then there exists a sub-sequence $X_{n_q}\stackrel{a.s.}{\rightarrow}0$, and so $X_{n_q}\stackrel{L^1}{\rightarrow}0$. Inequality $(2)$ now implies that $\max_{k\leq n_q}\left|\sum_{j=1}^k\xi_{j,n_q}\right|\stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} 0.$ which is not enough to conclude that $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Pls use the Lengart's inequality.

Comment: @JGWang you are right, with Lenglart inequality everything works.